# Django with aws s3 Restricted media files only visible to owner

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have a model which basically saves files/images for each particular user and only that user will be able to view his/her file, other users cannot view other's private files/images.

```py
def user_id_directory(instance, file):
    return f"{instance.id}/{file}"

class PrivateFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_id_directory)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using s3 to save media files, but using s3 will leave a link that can be accessed by any other user
Suppose there's a file called FILE1 which has an id 1, and I have created an API that returns the following JSON schema.

```
{
"id": 1,
"user": 1,
"image": "example.aws.com/Media/File/1/image.png?AccessID=...."
"created": "2021-09-09 09:09:09.25555",
}
```

If I give this link to anyone, even an unauthorized user will be able to view that file using that link, How can I restrict it to only the user who is the owner of the file, only he/she will be able to view it via the link.

Comment: How did you generate the image URL? It doesn't seem to be an [S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is what you would typically use in this case. Your application, of course, should only hand out a signed URL for a given file to the correct, authenticated client. If you prefer to proxy the download, then your app should validate the session corresponding to the download request.